# iPhone USB in Network preference pane missing. How to get it back?

Tags: macos, tethering

In the Network Preferences I miss an entry for iPhone (see Screenshot, same as for iPad). How can I get it back and connect to the Internet from Mac through iPhone using USB-C?[image: Network Preferences Pane]